Ubuntu 24.04 logout demand when I try to reduce an app's window size
Op Sys: 24.04.1 LTS
CPU: i5-7xxx
RAM: 16 GB
GPU: AMD Radeon R7 M445
Screen Compositor: X11 (Wayland causes Firefox and Thunderbird to flicker too much and disabling it is the only available remedy)
I usually get a system crash forcing logout when I try to reduce the window size from its maximum to a medium size, i.e. the double square button to the single square one.
It has happened with Sublime Text (v. 4180) and Firefox (v. 131.0.3).
It can also happen when more than one document is being viewed simultaneously with LibreOffice Writer. In fact, any mildly videographically challenging task seems to trigger this crash.
It is such an obvious cause that I wonder how it could have survived the routine testing done on op systems. Yet here it is.
To Reproduce: Open Firefox/ST on a wide-screen monitor and then open another app where you might need to have on half the screen so that content in Firefox may be compared with that in ST. Doing this requires you to reduce the screen width of each app to around half the monitor width.
You will find that the app whose screen is being reduced will not respond.
Then it shows this on the monitor

and you cannot do anything to unfreeze the screen bar click on the Logout button.
After all the work gone into Ubuntu over the years one would think that such basic videographic challenges should not come near GPU overload.

This is an ongoing GUI issue since 24.04 LTS. Anything that involves a sudden opening of a new window or major change to an existing window's content seems  to trigger this crash. Does Canonical take the stability of 24.04 seriously at all ?

It is indeed significant of the response from the Ubuntu community that this thread is being actively ignored. Not unlike issues arising with Ubuntu 24.04 installation lately.
